# Not able to run "java HelloWorld" error could not find main class

Tags: java, class, netbeans, program-entry-point

[image: It shows main method is not found in the class]

I generated HelloWorld.jar file using netbeans and tried executing in on windows 64-bit command prompt, Why?

My code is:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

I tried with another helloworld code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

It says could not find or load main class, why?

[image]

How to use java with multiple jar files, i am facing problem in this, here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually have your class in a package that you aren't showing us?

Comment: Start by moving back to the `coveragecodetool` directory.  Use `javac coveragecodetool/*.java` or `javac coveragecodetool/HelloWorld.java` to compile it.  Use `java coveragecodetool.HelloWorld` to run it.  This of course assumes that `HelloWorld` has the appropriate `package coveragecodetool` declaration.

Comment: Also, `Applet`s can't be run from the command line like this, you need to use the applet viewer and provide it a html page which defines the applet entry.  I'd avoid using applets for this and many other reasons while you are trying to get started, they are troublesome at the best of times, not to mention that most browsers are actively dropping support for them

Comment: Thanks it worked, but what if i have multiple jar files how do i run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to look more like

```
package coveragecodetool;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

At the command line, change to the directory which is ABOVE the `coveragecodetool` directory.

Use `javac coveragecodetool\HelloWorld.java` to compile the program and use `java coveragecodetool.HelloWorld` to run it

Comment: What if i have multiple jar files to attach with the helloworld program? In case of javac and java both how to use the jar files?

Comment: Either you need to specify the classpath using the `-cp` parameter directly to the `java/c` command or add them to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.  You can also include within the main jar's manifest class-path attribute.  You probably shouldn't have the jar's in the same directory as your source, but you probably shouldn't be compiling your `.class` files into your src directory either.  I'd highly recommend you find a modern IDE as it will help you solve many of these problems and or use a build system like Ant or Maven

Comment: E:\NetBeansProjects\Project24\CoverageCodeTool\src>java -cp ../dist/lib/* covera
gecodetool/CoverageCodeTool
Error: Could not find or load main class coveragecodetool.CoverageCodeTool

E:\NetBeansProjects\Project24\CoverageCodeTool\src>
I get the above error while adding multiple jar files.

Comment: I have created a CoverageCodeTool.class in the src folder itself.

Comment: Why are you using Netbeans by trying to compile it from the commandline?  Just have Netbeans compile and package it for you!  Also, I don't have the code for `CoverageCodeTool`, so I can only assume it doesn't have a `main` method and/or the correct `package` declaration`

Comment: I tried doing it from netbeans, but the generated jar file is not running after double clicking on it, so i want to see what errors command line is showing while running the jar file.

Comment: If it's a applet, then it will either need to be loaded through the applet viewer OR a web browser, in either case they will need a supporting HTML to define the `applet` tag/element.  Instead, use a `JPanel` as your base component and use the `main` method to create and add this component to a `JFrame`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing and [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).  The problem isn't with the jar file, it's with how you are trying to run it

Comment: what is the command to use multiple jar files with java command?

Comment: `java -cp {list of jars} {main class}` - but it won't work if you're still using a applet

Comment: i have removed the applet, using simple hello world with some more jar files. how do you specify the list of jars, is it ok to use: ../dist/lib/*?

Comment: So long as the relative can be resolved from your current location,  yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91536/discussion-between-mitesh-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: i tried using E:\NetBeansProjects\Project24\CoverageCodeTool\src>javac -cp ../dist/lib/* CoverageCodeTool.java it works it generates .class files
but when i try using java -cp ../dist/lib/* CoverageCodeTool, it gives me an error, could not find or load main class coveragecodetool

Comment: Does `CoverageCodeTool` have a package declaration?  Is it contained within the correct package structure?  Don't leave within the default package, it may not run

Comment: Okay, assuming that the class is in the coveragecodetool package AND it has the correct package deceleration, then you need to be in the direory ABOVE the coveragecodetool directory and use "coveragecodetool.CodeCoverageCodeTool" as the fully qualified class name when using java to execute it

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you have not defined a `main()` method. Hence it could not be found and (obviously) did not run.

The second example looks more promising, but you probably still need to specify a classpath to tell the JVM where the class is. Try following what you did for the first example. Take note of what package your second class is in. This must be included on the commandline, eg. `java <packagename>.HelloWorld`

Comment: The first example is an applet and doesn't need a `main` method, but it DOES need to be loaded via a html page using a browser or applet viewer

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say, it doesn't need a main method if it's run as an applet? If it's run from the command line as the OP did, it will, won't it?

Comment: Nope, the main method will run, but the applet doesn't have a "window" of it's own to be displayed it, so it's just a pointless exercise.  Applet's don't need a `main` method, because they are managed differently then "normal" applications